# false versus wrong

Tags: word-usage

"I like very much coffee."

- This sentence is **wrong**.
- This sentence is **false**.

Is it correct if I use either "wrong" or "false"?

The meanings of them in Cambridge Dictionary:

- false: not true or correct
- wrong: not correct

Comment: Have you looked up both words in a dictionary?

Comment: @myacorn Yes, I edited my question and added the meanings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way to understand the difference between the two words in this context is to define the words as follows

> False = Not True; while
>
> Wrong = Not Right.

If a sentence is **false**, the speaker is lying.

If a sentence is **wrong**, it is incorrect in some way.

Comment: "Two added to three equals six" is 'wrong' in some sense, at least in British English.

Answer (score 1):

If a sentence is so grammatically wrong that its meaning can't be understood, it isn't either true or false.

In your grammatically wrong example, there's no way to tell whether you like large quantities of coffee, or you just like a little bit of coffee a whole lot.

And that's without even considering whether you might be lying.

Comment: There are also things like "Good morning, Jack!" which are grammatically fine but just a greeting which is not capable of being true or false.